# Purchase not showing in GA4 Monetization

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, event-tracking, google-analytics-4

Using GA4 I have conversions on my WooCommerce store setup, and they work fine in that within debug mode I see conversion. Also, I can go to 'Conversions > purchase' in Google Analytics and see the conversion and the event value.  However, nothing appears on 'Monitization > Ecommerce purchases'.

The event name is 'purchase', and I believe I have the correct data layer variables.

This is my data layer:

```
{
  gtm: {start: 1616168568037, uniqueEventId: 2},
  event: 'purchase',
  ecommerce: {
    transaction_id: '222',
    currency: 'GBP',
    affiliation: 'My Store',
    value: '14.95',
    tax: '0.00',
    shipping: '5.95',
    items: [
      {
        item_name: 'Cocktail Shaker Kit',
        item_id: '199',
        price: '14.95',
        item_category: 'Cocktail Boxes',
        item_variant: '',
        quantity: 1,
        coupon: ''
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What have I missed?

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution yet?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem

Comment: Did you mark 'purchase' event as conversion in Events tab?

Comment: 'purchase' is marked as a conversion by default, and cannont be changed

Comment: Exact same problem for me, I saw this saying that it will work well after 24h
Is it the case ? https://imgur.com/a/21lt60Z

Answer (score 5):

For me it turned out that all it took was to add 'currency' parameter inside GA4 purchase tag. I found the answer here https://www.optizent.com/blog/ecommerce-report-in-ga4-not-showing-revenue/

I have currency set up on thank you page, but in current state of GA4 connected to tag manager, you have to define all parameters again in tag manager.

Answer (score 2):

Also, note that monetary values need to be sent as numbers instead of strings. I found that my purchase events were accepted but the revenue wasn't being calculated until I changed them to number values.

Comment: That's odd - the examples show strings, and even strings for quantity! https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ecommerce-ga4#measure_purchases

Answer (score 0):

They definitely can be delayed, howevever there is no harm in double checking your data being sent. I'm definitely not convinced that currency which is listed as optional makes any difference at all.

Also note that as with previous GA, the current date is not selected by default:

[image]

However even doing so, and it's currently 9:45am with plenty of real sales today I see nothing at all under **Monetization > Ecommerce Purchases** or **Conversions > Purchase**. I do however see the sales from yesterday evening when I first deployed it.

This seems to be a regression over the previous UA, where you could see sales in the equivalent places fairly soon. In fact I still have UA running in a different property, and all the transactions are showing for today.

So double check, then go to bed :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have problem with monetization report because I have little different structure then they have in official documentation. Please check documentation and make same events. Also you should wait for full report, informations about monetization aren't in real time.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/ecommerce?client_type=gtm